# Ruby Axlsx Gem Unlocking style on whole column

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby with the gem axlsx I've been trying to figure out how to set a style for an entire column and I haven't yet found it. The only way I've been able to do this is in a loop, setting each cell in the row to have the style I'd like, e.g.:

```
unlocked = wb.styles.add_style :locked => false
#...looping code here, assuming add_worksheet has been assigned to sheet
sheet.rows[rowNum].cells[columnNum].style = unlocked
```

I found out how to set a hidden attribute to an entire column:

```
sheet.column_info[3].hidden = true
```

And from the documentation I had thought this line would work:

```
sheet.column_info[0].style = unlocked
```

The strangest thing is that this style set line does not fail to apply and indeed querying it after looks to show the style is set to the corresponding number from the add_style return. However, on checking the produced spreadsheet it doesn't show the whole column as unlocked.

I know this can be done on a whole column quite easily using the write_xlsx gem so I wondered if it can be done using axlsx and I just can't find examples of the right syntax to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this you can use [`Worksheet#col_style`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Worksheet#col_style-instance_method) signature is `col_style(index,style,options={})`

**index**

The index of the row you want to set the style on (indexing starts at 0). Also index can be a range so if you want to unlock columns A though C then `sheet.col_style((0..2),unlocked)` will still work appropriately based on the way the code functions.

**style**

must be a predefined style as it is in the rest of the gem

**options ={}**

`options` allows you to set a row offset so if you didn't want to unlock the top n rows you could pass `row_offset: n` and all the cells in the column after `n` rows would be unlocked.
Example:

```
#unlock cells in column A starting at A3
sheet.col_style(0,unlocked,row_offset: 2)
```

**Full Example**

```
require 'axlsx'
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook
unlocked = wb.styles.add_style(locked: false)
wb.add_worksheet do |sheet|
  5.times { sheet.add_row [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  sheet.col_style(3,unlocked)
end
p.serialize('/simple_test.xlsx')
```

This will create a spreadsheet with 6 columns and the column with 4's (indexing starts at 0) will be unlocked while the rest of the columns remain locked (default).

**Additional Info**

The return value from this method will be a flat `Array` of the cells affected.

**Note:** the code does pretty much exactly what you are doing in your loop. It collects all the cells and then applies the style to each cell in a loop.